# How to properly compare UTC dates against Local date in LINQ to Enitites?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, date

I am having trouble getting data on a specified date using **LINQ**.

1. My dates are stored as **UTC** in the SQL database (`DateTime.UtcNow`).
2. I want to get all records for a date I or a user specifies on the browser (from a datepicker).

I am based in Australia and my database and site is hosted in another timezone and having trouble getting the results correctly.

I have tried using `timezoneOffset` from JavaScript and passing it to my controller to try converting **UTC** with the below code but still gives me incorrect results:

```
myRepo.Where(x => x.Date.AddMinutes(-(timezoneOffset)).Date == date.Date)
```

I've been scratching my head for almost 2 days already and haven't found a clear and proper solution online.

Help! :)

Comment: Javascript dates are UTC, the default is to display as local. What format to do you need?

Comment: @RobG I have no problem displaying the dates at all. The problem is pulling the correct data coz the dates are saved as UTC in the database. So if i have Nov 15, 2014 from the datepicker it doesn't mean all the dates in the database for Nov15 is "15", some could be "14" and won't be included in my results.

Comment: Can you get UTC from the date picker? If you can get a Date object then the UTC methods (e.g. [*getUTCDate*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.15) will return UTC values (you may have to format the string yourself).

Comment: I can definitely get UTCDate from datepicker before passing it to the controller, but that would give me the same results as mydate.ToUniversalTime().Date. I think the problem is that the UTC dates I hve stored in the database are not recognized as UTC dates in LINQ because the Kind is "Unspecified"...i'd expect it to be "UTC".